# How to open port in boinc useing iptables

Tags: iptables, boinc

witch code do i need to open boinc iptables ?

I need to connect to grcpool.com server

I found i need to open the port tcp and udp (31416)

i'm useing this code:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 31416 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 31416 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 31416 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 31416 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

but still does not works :/

Can anyone help me ??

Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score -1):

Hello i found out how to open the firewall iptables

Code:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 31416:34356 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 31416:34356 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 31416 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 31416 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```